# How to get a windows close/minimize buttons in top GNOME panel?

Tags: gnome-panel, applet

I want to get any application's close/minimize button in top gnome-panel. Please note that my top gnome-panel also has global-menu applet. Is there any app which can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to make the "Decoration Windows" in "Window decorations" inside CCSM blank and use Windows applets.
Thanks Andrew from Webupd8.

Answer (score 5):

You can the gnome panel window applets.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tsbarnes/misc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-window-applets
```

Once installed you will see two new panel applets. Window title and window buttons. Place them anywhere on the panel.

Comment: I tried it. But its not removing the title bar of the application. Basically, my top gnome-panel is in auto-hide mode. And whenever I open an application, the title bar of the app should not be there. Instead, it should be in the gnome-panel. I hope i am clear. There is a compiz setting which can remove the title bar, but I need it in my gnome-panel.

Comment: @user12016: see the Window Applets options. Because that's exactly what WIndow Applets does...

Comment: Agree with windows applets. But how do I make the title-bar of an application disappear, since I already have it in my gnome-panel now ?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the titlebar using the tips in http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1077662&page=2

I used the steps in modifying the theme xml file.

Comment: Could you please copy those steps into your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Its 2012 and Ubuntu 12.04 was released recently. Gnome windows applets also was recently updated to support Gnome 3. It is highly customisable now and it even can hide compiz decorations for maximised windows. A must have for any netbook and people who are looking to save vertical space.

Right now it only works for Gnome 3 classic/fallback version

1. Install fallback version (sudo apt-get install gnome-fallback-version)
2. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install gnome-window-applets

Thanks to Andrei of Webupd8.